# postgresql: ordered result

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I've a table that looks like:

```
 id | user_id | activity_id | activity_type | root_id | is_root | timestamp 
----+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------
  1 |       1 |           1 | text          |       1 |       1 |         5
  2 |       2 |           2 | text          |       1 |       0 |         6
  3 |       3 |           3 | text          |       1 |       0 |        10
  4 |       2 |          10 | text          |      10 |       1 |        50
  5 |       1 |          11 | text          |      10 |       0 |        90
  6 |       3 |          12 | text          |      10 |       0 |       100
  7 |       3 |          20 | text          |      20 |       1 |       190
  8 |       2 |          21 | text          |      20 |       0 |       130
  9 |       3 |          22 | text          |      20 |       0 |       150
 10 |       3 |          22 | text          |      20 |       0 |       150
 11 |       3 |          22 | text          |      20 |       0 |       150
```

I want an out put like

```
 id | user_id | activity_id | activity_type | root_id | is_root | timestamp 
----+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------
  7 |       3 |          20 | text          |      20 |       1 |       120
  8 |       2 |          21 | text          |      20 |       0 |       130
 11 |       3 |          22 | text          |      20 |       0 |       150
  9 |       3 |          22 | text          |      20 |       0 |       150
 10 |       3 |          22 | text          |      20 |       0 |       150
  4 |       2 |          10 | text          |      10 |       1 |        50
  5 |       1 |          11 | text          |      10 |       0 |        90
  6 |       3 |          12 | text          |      10 |       0 |       100
  1 |       1 |           1 | text          |       1 |       1 |         5
  2 |       2 |           2 | text          |       1 |       0 |         6
  3 |       3 |           3 | text          |       1 |       0 |        10
```

The root_id should be placed in one group, and the first row of that group should have is_root = 1. The groups should be sorted on the basis of timestamp of root DESC, but the children of the root should be sorted ASC (timestamp based)

`The relevant columns for the question is root_id, is_root, timestamp`.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about this?

```
ORDER BY root_id DESC, is_root DESC, timestamp
```

Comment: Ohh... right... it's simple :). I don't why it did not come in my head :(. Anyways, thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 2):

```
order by root_id desc, is_root desc, timestamp asc
```

should do the trick.