# PostgreSql: order result - II

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

REFER: [postgresql: ordered result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629785/postgresql-ordered-result)

I asked this question and accepted the answer. Well, at the time of asking I had something different in my mind, but I was convinced by the accepted answer. Well, I recently realized that the accepted answer is not something I wanted. Well, I'm restating the question:

I've a table which looks like:

```
 id | user_id | activity_id | activity_type | root_id | is_root | timestamp 
----+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------
  1 |       1 |           1 | text          |       1 |       1 |       200
  2 |       2 |           2 | text          |       1 |       0 |       206
  3 |       3 |           3 | text          |       1 |       0 |       210
  4 |       2 |          10 | text          |      10 |       1 |        50
  5 |       1 |          11 | text          |      10 |       0 |        90
  6 |       3 |          12 | text          |      10 |       0 |       100
  7 |       3 |          20 | text          |      20 |       1 |       120
  8 |       2 |          21 | text          |      20 |       0 |       130
  9 |       3 |          22 | text          |      20 |       0 |       150
 10 |       3 |          22 | text          |      20 |       0 |       150
 11 |       3 |          22 | text          |      20 |       0 |       190
```

The output that I'm looking for is:

```
 id | user_id | activity_id | activity_type | root_id | is_root | timestamp 
----+---------+-------------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------
  1 |       1 |           1 | text          |       1 |       1 |       200
  2 |       2 |           2 | text          |       1 |       0 |       206
  3 |       3 |           3 | text          |       1 |       0 |       210
  7 |       3 |          20 | text          |      20 |       1 |       120
  8 |       2 |          21 | text          |      20 |       0 |       130
 11 |       3 |          22 | text          |      20 |       0 |       150
  9 |       3 |          22 | text          |      20 |       0 |       150
 10 |       3 |          22 | text          |      20 |       0 |       190
  4 |       2 |          10 | text          |      10 |       1 |        50
  5 |       1 |          11 | text          |      10 |       0 |        90
  6 |       3 |          12 | text          |      10 |       0 |       100
```

- The root_id should be placed in one group, and the first row of that group should have is_root = 1.
- The groups should be sorted on the basis of timestamp of root DESC, but the children of the root should be sorted ASC (timestamp based)

`The relevant columns for the question is root_id, is_root, timestamp.`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
    id,
    user_id, 
    activity_id,
    activity_type,
    t.root_id,
    is_root,
    timestamp
from t
inner join (
    select root_id, max(timestamp) as root_id_max_timestamp
    from t
    group by root_id
) root_id_timestamp on t.root_id = root_id_timestamp.root_id
order by
    root_id_max_timestamp desc,
    is_root = 1 desc,
    timestamp
;
```

Your output sample data is not the same as the input. As example the timestamp of the input id #7 is 190 while the one of the output is 120. So check your output before you consider this query wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong input. input id# 7 should be 120. Thanks a lot.